# After merge 12 .csv Files in Python is the output .csv 50 Gigabyte

Tags: python, csv

I have **12** csv files with each **10,24** mbs. I have a code that joins / merged these csv files and returns them as a .csv. But I do not know how it comes to those 50 **Gigabyte**. I also break off. In other words, it would actually be even bigger.

```
from glob import glob

with open('outputParsed2.csv', 'a') as combinedFile:
    combinedFile.write('Date;Request(in ms)\n') # Headers
    for eachFile in glob('*.csv'):
        if eachFile == 'C:/user/xxx/Desktop/xxx/*.csv':

            pass
        else:
            count = 0
            for line in open(eachFile, 'r'):
                if count != 0:
                    combinedFile.write(line)
                count = 1
```

Does somebody has any idea?

[image]

Comment: That first `if` is never going to fire, so if you think you are filtering out something with it, you really aren't. I'd be afraid if the output is in the same directory as the input ...

Answer (score 0):

You are both reading and writing to `"outputParsed2.csv"` at the same time, resulting in an endless loop of reading/writing for that file. Exclude the file from the results of `glob('*.csv')` and everything should be fine.

Also, your first `if` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but "outputParsed2.csv" is not in the same directory with the "12 csv files". Also why exlude?

Comment: @harun You open `outputParsed2.csv` in the current directory and choose a filename from what's returned by `glob('*.csv')`, that is a list of `csv` files in the current directory. Maybe the files you would like to read are in another directory, but the file, one of the files, that you are _actually_ reading is, w/o any doubt, `outputParsed2.csv`

Comment: @gboffi What would you suggest how I can implement it?

Comment: just print the path of eachFile  and check the if it is the expected one or not or change to desired directory in code os.chdir("/mydir")

Comment: @harun I'd avoid python and use system commands, `echo "'Date;Request(in ms)" > outputParsed2.csv ; for csv in ... ; do sed -n "2,$p" $csv >> outputParsed2.csv ; done` — where in place of `...` you should place a glob expression that return the files you want to join.

Answer (score 0):

just print the path of eachFile  and check the if it is the expected file or not. Also you can change to desired directory in code using os.chdir("/mydir"). I noticed that you have opened outputParsed2.csv file in append mode which adds to existing data in the file .. You may want to open this as a fresh file

Comment: Thank you for your reply But unfortunately I did not understand what I should do now ..

Comment: try 'with open('outputParsed2.csv', 'w') as combinedFile:'

Comment: I try it out, but I cancel the run after the output was 2 gigabyte.

Comment: 12 * 1024mbs = 12288 mbs = 12.288 gb. so please wait until it reaches that limit

Comment: I cancel it on 20 gigabyte.